# Change default text editor to Micro. Doesn't appear in the "Open with" category

Tags: 20.04, text-editor, default-programs

I want to use the [Micro text editor](https://micro-editor.github.io/) as the default application to open various text files, but when I try to do the usual procedure:

Left-click > Properties > Open With...

I see that Micro doesn't exist as an option.

How can I do that?

Comment: Provide the source of "Micro text editor". How exactly did you install it?

Comment: @DKBose `sudo apt install micro`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Micro is a terminal-based text editor which doesn't come with a `.desktop` file typical of most graphical applications.

You can make `micro.desktop` in `~/.local/share/applications` with the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Exec=gnome-terminal -x micro %u
Name=Micro
MimeType=text/plain;text/x-chdr;text/x-csrc;text/x-c++hdr;text/x-c++src;text/x-java;text/x-dsrc;text/x-pascal;text/x-perl;text/x-python;application/x-php;application/x-httpd-php3;application/x-httpd-php4;application/x-httpd-php5;application/xml;text/html;text/css;text/x-sql;text/x-diff;

Icon=
```

(You can point to an icon of your choice and modify the `MimeType=` line to suit your usage.) Make `micro.desktop` executable. Now, when you right-click on a file in your file manager, you'll see `Micro` as an option in "Open with other application".

You can also set `Micro` as the default application. To do that with Nautilus, right-click on a target file, open its properties and do the needful there:

[image: Setting Micro as default]

Comment: Thank you that worked great! Just as a reference for anyone interested, I had to make the following modification to the answer, because I use Alacritty as a terminal emulator `Exec='usr/bin/alacritty -e micro %u`. This is a fault of mine, as Micro is a terminal-based emulator I had to have mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there a option to open with other application or somethng similar like select application on right click. if yes then choose application from there. If not then goto system > preferences > preferred application then choose micro text as defult text editor. If neither helped then try another file manager like caja. If none of these work you might need to report the issue to developer.